# Single linked list, issue with node insertion lowest to highest node values

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to build a linked-list while learning the language of C++, and implement a lowest-to-highest node insertion function. I have followed some tutorials on the internet and textbooks.

I have a Struct for the linked list Node setup as so:

```
struct Node {
 private:
  int _data;
  Node *_next = nullptr;
 public:
  Node () : _data ((int) (NULL)), _next (nullptr) { /* */ };
  explicit Node (int &value) : _data (*&value), _next (nullptr) { /* */ };
  friend class LL;
};
```

My LL class:

```
class LL {
 private:
  Node *first;
 public:
  LL () : first (nullptr)
  { /* */ };
  void PrintList ();
  void Push_front (int x);
  void Push_back (int x);
  void Delete (int x);
  void Clear ();
  void Reverse ();
  void LTH(int x);
};
```

Then my lowest to greatest class function is:

```
void LL::LTH(int x)
{
  Node *current = this->first;
  Node *newNode = new Node (x);
  if (this->first == NULL || (current->_data) >= newNode->_data)
    {
      newNode->_next = this->first;
      this->first  = new Node (x);
    }
  else
    {
      current = this->first;
      while (current->_next!=NULL &&
             current->_next->_data < newNode->_data)
        {
          current = current->_next;
        }
      newNode->_next = current->_next;
      current->_next = new Node (x);
    }
}
```

My LL:PrintList()

```
void LL::PrintList ()
{

  if (this->first == nullptr)
    {
      std::cout << "List is empty.\n";
      return;
    }

  Node *current = this->first;
  while (current != nullptr)
    {
      std::cout << current->_data << " ";
      current = current->_next;
    }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

My main

```
LL list;
// Changed to for-loop, original is reading binary data random integers
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    list.LTH(i);
  }

list.PrintList ();
```

It then is outputting lowest to highest, but skipping over some Nodes:

```
// Linked-List Nodes
41, 34, 74, 87, 33, 25, 69, 75, 85, 30, 79, 61, 38, 49, 73, 64, 57, 95, 61, 86

// Output: LL:LTH() (Lowest -> Highest)
25, 30, 38, 49, 57, 61, 86

// It's Missing (XX)
XX, XX, XX, XX, XX, 25, XX, XX, XX, 30, XX, 61, 38, 49, XX, XX, 57, XX, XX, 86
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with at least the Link-List class, and also the main, how you feed them.

Comment: @Vuwox I promise when I wrote this, I was trying to provide minimal code, because I had this comment flag last time for minimal, reproducible example and did not want to make the same mistake. I provided the Node struct & the function, what else would be considered reproducible? Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The Linked-list class, and the main.

Comment: Unless someone can cut and paste the few short lines of code from your question, compile, run and reproduce your problem, then by definition it's not reproducible. If it's more like a novel, rather than a few short lines of code, then it's not minimal. Do you think that the code, as shown, is a [mcve]?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I apologize as when I first encountered that flag, someone argued in what I was mentioned. I now completely understand, and appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Your insertion function has three `new` statement. It's intended purpose is to insert exactly one node. As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical. Obviously something is fundamentally wrong when there are three `new` statements instead of the expected one, and it is guaranteed that two of the three `new` statements will always execute. At the very least, you're leaking memory. Think hard about what your insertion logic would be, and, if needed, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your answer and response. Sometimes, you do not realize that something might not be logical that is why individuals seek help from people. And the emergency duck issue, I assure you I spent time debugging this issue. I also am blind, I have to code with speech, so it takes me time sometimes to see things that I actually cannot see. But none the less, I appreciate the information.

Comment: As stated by @SamVarshavchik, you have to create once and only once the `new node`, you are not suppose to use `new node(x)` more than once in the LTH function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started from the code in the tutorial linked in your question and I made some changes. Note that this is not the more "modern" way to implement this, but it could be a starting point to understand some of the involved mechanics.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class LinkedList;

class ListNode
{
    int data_ = 0;
    ListNode *next_ = nullptr;
public:
    ListNode() = default;
    ListNode(int a)
        : data_(a) {};
    // I added this constructor, it should ease the insertions
    ListNode(int a, ListNode *n)
        : data_(a), next_(n) {};

    friend class LinkedList;
};

class LinkedList{
private:
    ListNode *first_ = nullptr;
public:
    LinkedList() = default;
    // I didn't want to write down your example as a bunch of list.add(42)...
    LinkedList(std::initializer_list<int> lst)
    {
        for (auto i : lst)
            add(i);   
    }
    // Just to make the code more readable
    bool is_empty() const noexcept
    {
        return first_ == nullptr;
    }
    // Only a small set of function are implemented
    void add(int a);
    void print();
    void clear();
    // The tutorial didn't implement a destructor, but you should study about RAII
    ~LinkedList()
    {
        clear();
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList a {
        41, 34, 74, 87, 33, 25, 69, 75, 85, 30, 79, 61, 38, 49, 73, 64, 57, 95, 61, 86
    };

    a.print();
}

void LinkedList::add(int a)
{
    if (is_empty())
    {
        first_ = new ListNode(a);
    }
    else if (first_->data_ >= a)
    {
        first_ = new ListNode(a, first_);   
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode *current = first_;
        while ( current->next_  &&  current->next_->data_ < a )
        {
            current = current->next_;
        }
        current->next_ = new ListNode(a, current->next_);
    }
}

void LinkedList::print()
{
    if (is_empty())
    {
        std::cout << "List is empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << first_->data_;
        for ( ListNode *current = first_->next_; current != nullptr; current = current->next_)
        {
            std::cout << ", " << current->data_;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

void LinkedList::clear()
{
    for (ListNode *current = first_, *next; current; current = next)
    {
        next = current->next_;
        delete current;
    }
    first_ = nullptr;
}
```

It's testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ameif0VMaIKOTdn1), the output beeing

```
25, 30, 33, 34, 38, 41, 49, 57, 61, 61, 64, 69, 73, 74, 75, 79, 85, 86, 87, 95
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding later on. I just now caught this response and I appreciate it so much. I know it takes time to format a response like this, especially after an answer was accepted. But your answer truly is the best and helps explain the mechanics as you stated. It showed you truly wanted to help someone understand and learn, it also I feel is now the best answer given.

Comment: Also, thanks for telling me about RAII and deconstructors. I also learned that a struct compiles to a class, but the difference is between public or private

Comment: @Raymond You're welcome. If I may, the next thing you should consider is "the rule of five" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested, but imo it should work.

```
void LL::LTH(int x)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node (x);
    Node* lowest = this->first;

    // if smaller than the first one, add it to the beginning.
    if(lowest->_data > newNode->_data) {
        newNode->_next = lowest;
        this->first = newNode;        
    } else {  
        // Loop until at the right position.
        lowest = lowest->_next;
        while (lowest->_next!=NULL && lowest->_data < newNode->_data) {
            lowest = lowest->_next;
        }

        // If not on last, ensure to keep track of the next.
        if(lowest->_next != NULL) {
          newNode->_next = lowest->_next;                   
        }

        // insert at the current position.
        lowest->_next = newNode; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because my friend who is being my eyes for me and my keyboard says this was very intuitive and helpful. I am blind, and it is something I am trying to accomplish, learning to code. Even if it is untested, we feel we can figure something out with this. Thanks so much from both of us.

Comment: Did not work, I believe because the first insert is always null. Still working on it.